# strcpy_s unhandled exception?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use `strcpy_s`, but I'm having this error:

> Unhandled Exception...

```
struct Item { 
    //Item's 
    int code; // Code 
    char* name[20];  

    int amount; //Amount in stock 
    int minAmount; //Minimum amount

    float price; //Price
};
```

The important lines are the beginning and the line with the `"@@@@@@@@@"` beside it. (`spot = 0`, `name` string was received, `store` was initialized in `main()`).

```
    //add an item to store
void addItem(Item* store, int maxItems, int &numItems)
{
    if (maxItems == numItems)
    {
        cout << "ERROR \n";
        return;
    }

    int spot = numItems; // our item's spot in store[]
    int code; // inputted code

    //Item's attributes' input

    cout << "enter code : \n"; //code
    cin >> code;
    store[spot].code = code; //Code

    cout << "enter name : \n"; //Name

    _flushall();
    char* name = new char[20];
    gets_s(name, 20);

    numItems++; //forward the number of items

    strcpy_s(*store[spot].name, 20, name); //Name UNHANDLED EXCEPTION @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

    cout << "enter amount : \n"; //Amount in stock

    do
    {
        cin >> store[spot].amount;

        if (store[spot].amount < 0) //not negative
            cout << "ERROR \n";

    } while (store[spot].amount < 0);

    cout << "enter minimum amount : \n"; //Minimum amount for orders

    do
    {
        cin >> store[spot].minAmount;

        if (store[spot].minAmount < 0) //not negative
            cout << "ERROR \n";

    } while (store[spot].minAmount < 0);

    cout << "enter price : \n"; //Price

    do
    {
        cin >> store[spot].price;

        if (store[spot].price < 0) //not negative
            cout << "ERROR \n";

    } while (store[spot].price < 0);
}
```

Comment: That command is supposed to check if we've reached the maximum items, so I think it's fine... Thanks though :]

Comment: remove `*` --> `strcpy_s(store[spot].name, 20, name);`

Comment: "*You should ignore most of the code*" Then don't post it to begin with. See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sry, I've just edited it.

Comment: `Item::name` is an array of 20 `char*` pointers, it's not a 20 character buffer. You probably want to take out the `*` in the definition. Otherwise, the pointers need to be set to point to a valid buffer that you can copy your string into.

Comment: YES :DDDD Thank you so much [simplicis - you too]!

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to test calling `strcpy_s` and every other suspicious part of the code separately and see it there is any problem, if there is, work around it and then insert it in the `addItem` function.

From is visible in the posted code, you seem to be passing a pointer variable with the dereference operator in front of it in most of the functions you use, for example the signature of `strncpy_s()` is:

```
errno_t strncpy_s(char *restrict dest,
                  rsize_t destsz,
                  const char *restrict src,
                  rsize_t count);
```

You need to pass the first parameter without the `*` as it is a pointer: `Item* store`, i.e. as pass it as: `store[spot].name`.

Check [this article about pointer assignment](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/), which will help you understand how to [pass a pointer as an argument to a function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm).

---

**Edit after a comment**

Your second error message could be because the member `name` of `store` is not a pointer, you probably need to pass it using `&` operator, i.e. pass its address:

```
strcpy_s(&store[spot].name, 20, name);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I firstly did [I think], but I get the "no instance of overloaded function "strycpy_s" matches the argument list. Argument types are: (char*[20], int, char*)". :(

Comment: That is because the member `name` of `store` is not a pointer, you probably need to pass it using `&` operator, i.e. pass its address.

Comment: Could you show me how? I can't seem to make it work :)

Comment: @Yair I would advice you to test calling the `strcpy_s` separately and see it there is any problem, if there is, work around it and then insert it in the `addItem` function. Unfortunately, I doubt that there is anything that could be done, on this stage.